# Facebook registration protocol

Tags: c#, facebook, httpwebrequest

I am making a marketing tool that is required to register facebook accounts using web requests. I have been trying to understand the protocol but I always end up with a "Sorry there is something went rong" page. Any explanations are appreciated =].

Regards

edit: I am trying to let the user to register on facebook through my application. He should input the required fields (names,birthday,email) and the application should do the signup process for him after he solves the captcha that will be fetched from facebook. It's not a spam attempt, Don't bother saying you won't answer because it's a spam attempt. If you think so, just don't answer.

edit: I don't want to use any WebBrowser controls, I need it to be through HTTP Requests.

edit: I try to imitate requests sent to facebook from my computer using fiddler, I believe I imitated everything that facebook website does. Though I still getting "Sorry something went wrong" page.

Comment: you should be clearer about the request you tried.

Comment: Automatic registration of accounts sounds like what a spammer would do

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I wouldn't have said that so early, leave him a chance to explain ;)

Comment: I updated the question hoping it's more clear now.

Comment: Even if you do that, though, there must be Ts&Cs and privacy agreements that the user is implicitly accepting without being displayed. Won't it be easier and safer to show them the website and switch your app to a Facebook connect login screen, so they have to sign-up manually before they can continue?

Comment: @Rup: It would work but I would like it to go all from inside my application.

Answer (score 0):

You have several API to to that. I recommend that you use the last one, the graph API. Then you have several SDK, I know PHP and Javascript SDK.

In javascript, with jQuery you can do

```
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="login">Login</button>
    <button id="logout">Logout</button>
    <button id="disconnect">Disconnect</button>
  </div>
  <div id="user-info"></div>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

  <script>
    // initialize the library with the API key
    FB.init({ apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY' });

    // fetch the status on load
    FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse);

    $('#login').bind('click', function() {
      FB.login(handleSessionResponse, {
        // here you specify the perms your application requires
        perms:'publish_stream, offline_access, manage_pages, read_stream'
      });
    });

    $('#logout').bind('click', function() {
      FB.logout(handleSessionResponse);
    });

    $('#disconnect').bind('click', function() {
      FB.api({ method: 'Auth.revokeAuthorization' }, function(response) {
        clearDisplay();
      });
    });

    // no user, clear display
    function clearDisplay() {
      $('#user-info').hide('fast');
    }

    // handle a session response from any of the auth related calls
    function handleSessionResponse(response) {
      // if we dont have a session, just hide the user info
      if (!response.session) {
        clearDisplay();
        return;
      }

      // if we have a session, query for the user's profile picture and name
      FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response) { 
          $('#user-info').html(JSON.stringify(response));
      });
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

This example is taken from the documentation of the JavaScript SDK. You need to get you API_KEY from the facebook developper page http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php

Comment: That should work if the user already have a facebook account. You didn't get my question.

Comment: Ah yes sorry I believed you wanted to register the user in your application, not in facebook itself. Sorry for the confusion.